# Echoing mulitple error and success messages using header function in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo out messages into my first page after submitting data in the server to the database.

My system will check for a conflict. If there is no conflict then the system will echo out the success message and if there is then the error message.

I already did that with one message but I want to echo out multiple messages depending on the data the user submits using the checkboxes.

For example:
if the user checks 3 checkboxes which contain days like monday, wednesday, and friday then the system will check, the data will be submitted to the server and to the database.

There is no problem with data. I already have the function but the problem is in the message in the header. I want to print

```
success = monday, success = wednesday, success = friday
```

but in my existing code only this will be printed `success = friday`. The last checkbox that is checked will be echoed. But all of those data is sent. The problem is the message return after sending.

Here's my first page code for echoing the message

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
  $message = $_GET['error'];
  echo '<div class="error">' .$message.'</div>';
} else {
  $message = $_GET['success'];
  echo '<div class ="success">' .$message. '</div>';
}
?>
```

Then the code in my server using the header function

```
if (($count_t == 0) and ($count_r == 0) and ($count_s == 0)) //the conflict being detected if there is none then proceed 
{
  mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into schedule (timeID, subject, instructorID, day, room, strand, section, grade, semester) VALUES 
                ('$daym','$subject','$ins', 'm','$room', '$strand', '$section', 'Grade 11', '1st Semester')");  

  header("Location:../pages/1stschedules11.php?success=schedule created for Monday on $time_t ");
} //if there is confict
else if ($count_t>0){
  header("Location:../pages/1stschedules11.php?error=Monday $timei  $member1-- not available");
} 
else if ($count_r>0) {
  header("Location:../pages/1stschedules11.php?error=Monday $timer  $rooms-- not available"); 
}
else 
{
  header("Location:../pages/1stschedules11.php?error=Monday $times  $strands $sections-- not available");
}
}
```

Comment: IMO much better to return to JS and handle via that

Comment: The problem description needs some more work, and the error string [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) at least.

Comment: It would be better practice to not redirect after submitting the form, and detect if the request is `post` or `get` to determine whether to process the form or serve the form. Then without redirects all of your variables are localized to php, and you can just use them directly in the template as needed. This is part of why the vast majority of sites post forms to the same page that served them (if request is get, show the form, if it's post, process the form). If on post there are errors, you can just queue them and call the render function directly from there.

Comment: sir can you show me how it's done sir, so I can understand more @mopsyd